# Kubernetes delete POD with hostPath data files

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

I am new to Kubernetes, I am creating POD on run time to push data and after pushing and collecting data I am deleting POD.

For the processing of files I have connected SSD. and assigned its path as **hostPath: /my-drive/example** while creating POD. Now when i run my POD i can see the files in defined path.

But, Now I just wanted to delete files created by POD in a hostPath directory while deleting POD. is it possible?

My POD file looks like.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pod-example
  labels:
    app: pod-example
spec:
  containers:
  - name: pod-example
    image: "myimage.com/abcd:latest"
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    workingDir: /pod-example
    env:
    volumeMounts:
    - name: "my-drive"
      mountPath: "/my-drive"
  volumes:
  - name: "my-drive"
    persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
    hostPath:
      path: /my-drive/example
  restartPolicy: Never
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: regcred
  affinity:
    podAntiAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - labelSelector:
          matchExpressions:
          - key: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
            operator: In
            values:
            - my-node
        topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
```

Comment: Can you use a Kubernetes-managed persistent volume (maybe changing this to a StatefulSet)?  You should almost never use `hostPath` directories, since they have a number of practical problems (most notably, you can misplace data if a pod is deleted and recreated on a different node).  If the data is in a persistent volume then `kubectl delete pvc` will delete it.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using `lifecycle` hooks in K8s. Under them, `preStop` hook can be used here since you need to do action when stopping the pod.

Check docs related to lifecycle hooks: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/

If you exact know the files or let's say a directory to delete, you can use `Exec` hook hanlder. Check the sample below that I've added for your reference.

```
lifecycle:
  preStop:
    exec:
      command:
        - "sh"
        - "-c"
        - >
          echo "Deleting files in my-drive/example/to-be-deleted" > /proc/1/fd/1 # Add preStop hook's stdout to main process's stdout
          rm -r my-drive/example/to-be-deleted
```

P.S. According to your problem statement, you are not using the POD continuously it seems. If the task that you are looking is to execute periodically or not continuous, I would suggest you to select either K8s `CronJob` or `Job` rather a `POD`.
Make sure to have required user access inside the container to delete files/floders.

Comment: Sir, let me try this this solution looks like what i am looking for....

btw I am just using pod for specific purpose from a python script and i also destroys them using same script. it takes 10 minutes....  Mean while it generates somefiles in the directory. But files remains there after deletion.

Comment: If you are using the pod for a specific requirement, that is fine. Hope my solution will fit to you.

Comment: It only delete files inside container... (kubectl exec -it m-pod --/bin/sh) 

if I mount hostPath.. i can porcess and see files on the mounted direcectory without accessing files

Comment: @RogBoy, we can only delete files in the mounted directory. e.g. if there is test.txt file in the volume such as /my-drive/example/test.txt, this can be deleted. If the above provided logic doesn't work, you can try deleting the file inside the logic executed inside the container. `lifecycle` hook should be triggered before killing the pod in order to use the logic I have added in the answer. Further, you do not need to use pod anti afinity and PVM policies for `hostPath` volume mounts.
Check docs for `hostPath` volume mount: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath

Answer (score 0):

Update persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy to Delete as shown below

```
persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
```

Comment: But I am not using PV, I am directly using hostPath. I dont think so if i can use this with hostPath.

Comment: if you dont use Local persistent volume then you will have to manually delete that mount path

Comment: So for I am creating PODs using script... so If I assign PV only in POD settings ... is it enough... of do i need to delete claim as well to delete data. ?

Because deletion of PV and Claim isnt possible for us right now.

Comment: if you assign pv on pod definition then you will have to manually delete the pv after the pod is deleted

Comment: so is there any work around to delete local-storage automatically while deleting POD ?

Comment: you need to go with Local persistent volume. Following link would be helpful --> https://lapee79.github.io/en/article/use-a-local-disk-by-local-volume-static-provisioner-in-kubernetes/